Why does my SimpleRNN model in Sequential API show '?' for output shape and zero trainable parameters when using Embedding layers?
I'm building a SimpleRNN model with an Embedding layer in Keras and encountering an issue when using the Sequential API. The model summary shows the output shape as ? and the number of trainable parameters as 0. However, when I build the same model using the Functional API, everything works as expected.
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Embedding, SimpleRNN, Dense

model = Sequential([
    Embedding(input_dim=10000, output_dim=50, input_length=100),
    SimpleRNN(32),
    Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

I get the following output:
Output shape: ?
Trainable parameters: 0(unbuilt)

However, when I use the Functional API, like this:
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Embedding, SimpleRNN, Dense

inputs = Input(shape=(100,))
x = Embedding(input_dim=10000, output_dim=50)(inputs)
x = SimpleRNN(32)(x)
outputs = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)

model = Model(inputs, outputs)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

The model works fine with the correct output shape and trainable parameters.
Could anyone explain why this is happening with the Sequential API and how I can resolve this issue? Am I missing something in the configuration for Sequential?

This issue is because the model has not been built yet. To get the required output shapes, you need to build the model first by                                                                                                          calling the build() or by feeding it some input data and then re-complile the model.
Please check the below code lines to get the desired output:
Build the model
model.build(input_shape=(None, 10))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

Output:
Model: ""sequential_1""
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃ Layer (type)                         ┃ Output Shape                ┃         Param # ┃
┡━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┩
│ embedding_2 (Embedding)              │ (None, 10, 50)              │         500,000 │
├──────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│ simple_rnn_2 (SimpleRNN)             │ (None, 32)                  │           2,656 │
├──────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│ dense_2 (Dense)                      │ (None, 1)                   │              33 │
└──────────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────┴─────────────────┘
 Total params: 502,689 (1.92 MB)
 Trainable params: 502,689 (1.92 MB)
 Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 B)"

